Polar form of the sum of two complex numbers.
I was trying to express the addition of two complex numbers only in function of its absolute values and arguments while preserving the result in polar form, with the fewest terms possible, for simplicity. A solution using a combination of rectangular (real and imaginary parts) and polar forms was presented here.
So, for $a, b, c \in \mathbb{C_{\neq 0}}$,
$$a+b = c = |c|e^{i{\langle c \rangle}},$$
where $\langle c \rangle$ is the argument of $c$.
For |c|, similar to the law of cosines,
$$|c| = \sqrt{|a|^2 +|b|^2 +2|a||b|\cos({\langle b \rangle}-{\langle a \rangle})}.$$
For ${\langle c \rangle}$, geometrically, thinking in terms of the "projections" of $b$ onto $a$, the expression that I ended up with was:
$${\langle c \rangle} = {\langle a \rangle} +\arctan\left( \frac{ |b|\sin({\langle b \rangle}-{\langle a \rangle}) }{ |a| +|b|\cos({\langle b \rangle}-{\langle a \rangle}) } \right).$$
The full expression would be:
$$a+b = c = \sqrt{|a|^2 +|b|^2 +2|a||b|\cos({\langle b \rangle}-{\langle a \rangle})} \left( e^{i} \right)^{\textstyle{ {\langle a \rangle} +\arctan\left( \frac{ |b|\sin({\langle b \rangle}-{\langle a \rangle}) }{ |a| +|b|\cos({\langle b \rangle}-{\langle a \rangle}) } \right) }}.$$
But the problem is that if $a$ is within a circular region that has $0$ as one of the points of its circumference and it is centered at $-\frac{1}{2}b$, then this way of representing $a+b$ results in $-(a+b)$ instead.
Outside of this region, everything is fine. But I can't find other expressions that don't use rectangular form or that are invalid for arguments beyond $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians that solve this.
What would it be a solution to this error? Is it possible only with the function $\mathrm{atan2}$?

Personally, I regard your overall approach as bad.  When multiplying two (non-zero) complex numbers, polar coordinates work well.  When adding two complex numbers, rectangular coordinates is (by far) best.  This explains the difficulty that you encountered in attempting to find examples where two complex numbers were added, but rectangular coordinates were not used.

I totally agree that for addition rectangular form is the best. However, I made this question because I can't find many examples of polar form used for addition. And when I find, they are presented without simplifying the expressions for the absolute value and the argument. In rectangular form, there is the simple expression $a+b = (\Re a +\Re b) + i(\Im a +\Im b)$, which expresses the sum in rectangular form. The same for the product in rectangular form, $(\Re a \Re b - \Im a \Im b) +i(\Re a \Im b + \Im a \Re b)$, which I would say is pretty simple. Then what would be for polar complex sum?

Again, I suggest that you abandon any idea of polar complex sum, and focus merely on $~re^{i\alpha} \times se^{i\beta} = rs \times e^{i(\alpha + \beta)}.$
